# Symfony2: How to get asset's URL in function inside view template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

As documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets) I can read my image files in view by using following code.

```
<img src="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png') ?>" alt="Symfony!" />
////  This outputs the image
```

**or I can also do**

```
<?php 
    echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png'); 
    // echoes --->  /assets/images/logo.png
?>
```

However, my views are much complex and I want to divide different sections of view in functions. So when I write the above code in a function, it doesn't work.

```
function one(){
    echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png'); 
}
one();
Notice: Undefined variable: view in ....\Resources\views\Section\splash.html.php on line 12

Fatal error: Call to a member function getUrl() on a non-object in ....\Resources\views\Section\splash.html.php on line 12
```

Can someone please guide me how can I get this to work?

---

This is my full view file.

```
<?php
echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png') . "<br><br>";

function one(){
    echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png') . "<br><br>";
}
one();
?>
<img src="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png') ?>" alt="no image" />
```

---

This is how I am calling the view from my controller

```
return $this->render('MySimpleBundle:Section:splash.html.php');
```

Comment: did you already changed the templating engine to php ?

Comment: @Nextar Yes I have. My php code `<?php 
    echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png'); 
    // echoes --->  /assets/images/logo.png
?> ` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "one()" has his own variable scope, so you have to pass the url into the function
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
function one($url)
{
    echo $view['assets']->getUrl($url) . "<br><br>";
}
```

anyway, in my opinion you should use simply:

```
<img src="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png') ?>" alt="Symfony!" />
```

to render the image, if your view gets to complex, it is may the right time to switch to a  powerful templating engine like twig

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed the basic variable scope issue? I had realized it short time after asking but +1 for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is the variable `$view` as the notice says.

You should either pass `$view` as a parameter or declare it global inside the function scope:

```
function one($view) {
    echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png');
}
```

or

```
function one() {
    global $view;
    echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png');
}
```

Comment: This is mostly my answer copied, anyway using global variables is a bad practise and should ever be avoided

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed the basic variable scope issue? I had realized it short time after asking but +1 for answering.

Comment: @Nextar oh yeah, sorry about that. i should have placed a comment instead. And global variables is indeed bad practise and should have been mentioned :)